# HTTP 302 Code while calling createEnvelope() Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign with my website. I am going to use embedded signing. For this, I have used JWT Authentication. After Authentication, I generated access token. With the help of access token I am trying to call createEnvelope('--account_id--', '--envelop_definition--'), but, I am getting HTTP 302 response.
Here is my code

```
<?php
    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('../config/docusignConfiguration.php');
    use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient;
    use DocuSign\eSign\Configuration;
    class DocumentSigner{
        private $jwtUserToken = null;
        private $envelope_api = null;
        public function getAccessManinderToken(){
            if(!$this->jwtUserToken){
                $this->jwtUserToken = $this->getJwtUserToken();
            }
            return $this->jwtUserToken[0]->getAccessToken();

        }
        private function getJwtUserToken(){
            global $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG;
                $apiClient = new ApiClient();
                $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['base_path']);
                $jwtToken = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                    $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['client_id'], 
                    $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['user_id'], 
                    $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['rsa_key'], 
                    $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['scope']
                );
                return $jwtToken;
        }


        public function make_envelope()
        {
            $demo_docs_path = '../documents/Sample';
            $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . ".pdf");
            $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);
            # Create the document model
            $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
                'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
                'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
                'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
                'document_id' => 1 # a label used to reference the doc
            ]);
            # Create the signer recipient model
            $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ # The signer
                'email' => 'check@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Checker Singh',
                'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
                # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
                'client_user_id' => 1000
            ]);
            # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
            $sign_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
                'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
                'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
            ]);
            # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
            # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
            $signer->settabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here]]));
            # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
            $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
                'email_subject' => "Please sign this document sent from the PHP SDK",
                'documents' => [$document],
                # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
                'recipients' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
                'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
            ]);
            return $envelope_definition;
        }


        public function generate(){
            global $DOCUSIGN_CONFIG;

            # Create the envelope request object
            $envelope_definition = $this->make_envelope();
            # Call Envelopes::create API method
            # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
            $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
            $config->setHost($DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['base_path']);
            $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessManinderToken());
            $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($config);
            $api_client->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($DOCUSIGN_CONFIG['base_path']);
            // var_dump($api_client->getUserInfo($this->getAccessManinderToken()));
            $this->envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
            

            try{
              $results = $this->envelope_api->createEnvelope('23c46058-c4e4-4101-8ddc-8f3f317a6e30', $envelope_definition);
              return $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
            }
            catch(DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException $e){
                var_dump($e); 
            }
            
        }


        

    }

    $documentSigner = new DocumentSigner();
    // echo $documentSigner->getAccessToken();
    var_dump($documentSigner->generate());





    
           
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you have for setHost is the account server which is used for API calls related to authentication. I'm thinking that you'd instead want: https://demo.docusign.net which is the base URL for the eSignature endpoints
(Try that, and if that doesn't work, could you try https://demo.docusign.net/restapi).

In general, it looks like that code may have originally come from example code that DocuSign hosts

Code example links: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/code-launchers/
PHP example:
https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/EG001EmbeddedSigning.php